# Create unique Number for email

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have an IOS app that takes a photo of a hazard, and sends the photo, along with some additional information, in an email. i want to generate a unique number for the email. this must be a unique number no matter how many users there are who have downloaded the app (ie - i cant just use a random number generator because it is possible someone else could generate the  same random number.)

Any suggestions, tutorials, comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at NSUUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood from your question, you need a key which is globally unique. Then, using an integer will not be a good solution. You need to use string.

I suggest using the following code for creating one...

```
NSString * uniqueKey = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
```

I hope it helps...